# Do images and kernels of invariant modules have the form $Mr$ and $\text{Ann}(r)$ respectively for some $r\in R$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, projective-module, finitely-generated, injective-module

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $N$ a submodule of $M$.  $N$ is said to be a **fully invariant** submodule of $M$ if $f(N)\subseteq N$  for all $f\in \text{End}_R(M)$.  We call an $R$-module $M$ invariant if each of its submodules is fully invariant.

In Lemma 1.1 of the paper (*Duo Modules* by A. C. Ozcan, A. Harmanci and  P. F. Smith), it is proved that
**a right $R$-module $M$ is an invariant module if and only if for each endomorphism $f$ of $M$ and each element $m$ of $M$ there exists $r$ in $R$ such that $f(m) = mr$**.   Here it means that any $m\in M$ determines an element of $R$ such that $f(m)$ is right multiplication by $r$.

**My question here is:**  How does the whole image $f(M)$ and the kernel $\ker(f)$ of $M$ under $f$ look like in terms of elements of $R$?  I know $f(M)$ is also right multiplication by some element of $R$ but which one and how?  Is it $f(M)=Ma$ where $a=(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n)$ for some sequence of elements in $R$?

For the kernel, I think the following: $$\ker(f)=\{m_i\in M:f(m_i)=0\}=\{m_i\in M:m_ia_i=0~\text{for some}~a_i\in R\}=\{m_i\in M:m_i\in\text{Ann}(a_i)~\text{for some}~a_i\in R\}=\bigcup_{a_i\in R}\text{Ann}(a_i),$$ where $\text{Ann}(a_i)$ is the left annihilator of $a_i$ in $M$.

I need some help to understand on how the entire images and kernels are determined by the right multiplication by the ring element?

Comment: I din't know!  Let me edit.

Comment: Also, note $m0 =0$ for any $m\in M$, thus the second equality does not hold